# How to schedule a scenario in SAP PI?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, business-process-management, sap-pi, sap-xi

I am looking for a way to schedule and automatically trigger a SOAP to FILE interface in PI. There is no external system and the SOAP sender acts like a trigger to start the process. The actual process is BPM to gather data from several RFC sources and to produce a report.

It appears that the only option is to use a Java Scheduler. I am able to specify my interface (it is not a selectable option, just a text entry that I am able to make). What is missing is a mechanism to specify the payload of a message, so Java Scheduler is not an option.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: So your scenario is looks like ETL, not ESB?

Comment: @Iliya Kuznetsov - my process gets triggered by a SOAP request. but the request itself does not contain anything - it is used to start a BPM process. The BPM process calls a number of BAPIs to get some data and writes that data to a csv file. I agree that this is a backwards approach. The reason for this approach is to make it a generic process to extract various info types based on the request.  I was able to create a custom entry in Java Scheduler in PI by following this tutorial: https://blogs.sap.com/2013/08/31/now-schedule-your-nw-business-process-in-nwa-job-scheduler/. It does not work.